# Can we force a new kitten with the same dimensions?

Tags: images

I apologize if the title sounds odd, but I am trying to find out if I can get different kittens using the same url from the image placeholder service http://placekitten.com

As per usage,a url like `http://placekitten.com/200/300` or `http://placekitten.com/g/200/300` should place the following kitten if properly given as `src` to an html image element.

[image]

I've tried appending random unique query strings.

`http://placekitten.com/g/200/300?_=1`

It still loads the same kitten...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were close with the query string...

You can request a specific "kitten" by using the `image` URL parameter with the number of the "kitten". For example:

```
http://placekitten.com/200/300?image=12
```

There appears to be 16 kittens numbered `1` to `16` (URL parameter value).

A number < 1 returns kitten `1`.

A number > 16 returns kitten `16`.

Reference:
http://placekitten.com/attribution.html

Answer (score -1):

I tried that link and it does not seem to work.  I checked out the placehold.io site that "inspired" the kitten site and that will show you a placeholder image.  While I can see kitten images in the attribution page, placing placekitten's sample code into a browser brought up only a blank placekitten page - no image at all.  While the options below are not as simple, since that site does not appear to function correctly you could:

A. There are plenty of free image sites around, you could use flickr.com or pixabay.com. Much like the ImageInject WordPress plugin you could add some code to search for kitten images and then add the first found to your site. You could use the Flickr API to create your search and retrieve the images. Here's a link to a [wiki](https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/Flickr+API) with resources on that API if you're interested.  May not be the best solution as you may have little control over the kitten shown.

B.  Another option is to use your own image repository. Take a few public domain images and upload them to a library. Then you can have a placeholder image inserted from your library.  It is not hard to randomize with a bit of code, HTML and JavaScript, or whatever you prefer.  For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Random Image</title>
     <script src="script10.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="script01.css">
</head>
<body>
     <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="305" height="312" id="myPicture" alt="some image">
</body>
</html>
```

Then use a random number function (like JavaScript's Math.random) to generate a random number, put the images into an array and that into a variable like Kitten which is passed to a Pick a Random Image function like this:

```
 window.onload = choosePic;

var Kitten = new Array("images/kit1.jpg","images/kit2.jpg","images/kit3.jpg");

function choosePic() {
     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * Kitten.length);
     document.getElementById("myPicture").src = Kitten[randomNum];
```

(Thanks to PeachPit.com for the code example, the full explanation and code is at: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2239154&seqNum=10 )

Comment: This isn't answering the question about getting a _different_ image.